# Can pandas read c++ binary file directly?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large file, which is outputed by my c++ code.

it save struct into file with binary format.

For example:

```
Struct A {
  char name[32]:
  int age;
  double height;
};
```

output code is like:

```
std::fstream f;
for (int i = 0; i < 10000000; ++ i)
  A a;
  f.write(&a, sizeof(a));
```

I want to handle it in python with pandas DataFrame.

Is there any good methos that can read it elegantly?

Comment: You should be able to write a pure Python reader for this; look into `struct` and/or `ctypes`, or the third-party module `cffi`.

Comment: @tripleee ok, thanks. i think if pandas can give a interface like: ```pd.read_bin```, that would be perfect :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Searching for `read_bin` I found this
[issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/6305#issuecomment-34548666) that suggests using `np.fromfile` to load the data into a numpy array, then converting to a dataframe:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

dt = np.dtype(
    [
        ("name", "S32"),   # 32-length zero-terminated bytes
        ("age", "i4"),     # 32-bit signed integer
        ("height", "f8"),  # 64-bit floating-point number
    ],
)

records = np.fromfile("filename.bin", dt)
df = pd.DataFrame(records)
```

Please note that I have not tested this code, so there could be some problems in the data types I picked:

- the byte order might be different (big/small endian `dt = np.dtype([('big', '>i4'), ('little', '<i4')])`)
- the type for the char array is a null terminated byte array, that I think will result in a `bytes` type object in python, so you might want to convert that to string (using `df['name'] = df['name'].str.decode('utf-8')`)

More info on the data types can be found in the numpy [docs](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.dtypes.html).

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Untested, based on a quick review of the Python [`struct` module's documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html)

```py
import struct

def reader(filehandle):
    """
    Accept an open filehandle; read and yield tuples according to the
    specified format (see the source) until the filehandle is exhausted.
    """
    mystruct = struct.Struct("32sid")
    while True:
        buf = filehandle.read(mystruct.size)
        if len(buf) == 0:
            break
        name, age, height = mystruct.unpack(buf)
        yield name, age, height
```

Usage:

```py
with open(filename, 'rb') as data:
    for name, age, height in reader(data):
        # do things with those values
```

I don't know enough about C++ endianness conventions to decide if you should add a modifier to swap around the byte order somewhere. I'm guessing if C++ and Python are both running on the same machine, you would not have to worry about this.